# Make mesh with specific volume material based on real data set

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes, import, csv

I have a question about visualizing real data. I have a set of points (hundreds of thousands) stored in a CSV file. Each point is defined by a position (X, Y and Z coordinates) and a fourth parameter - the density of the environment (in the range of 0-100 %). The data represent the distribution of a substance (gas) in the space.

I would like to create a 3D model that shows the distribution of the gas. I can import all the points into Blender using Geometry Nodes. However, I don't know how to work with the density parameter. Is there a way to assign a density to each point and then from points create a mesh with volume shader (corresponding to the density of the gas)?

Something like this (the picture shows a render of a cube with volume shader, which represents the variable density):

[image]

I tried to use a "Point to volume" Geometry node and then a "Volume to Mesh" Geometry node for my data. But without success.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: do you need it to be a mesh? it sounds better to use a volume.  how would the mesh show the Density? I'm confused. would you use a material?